# LINQ ForEach not setting members

Tags: c#, linq

I ran into an issue where I noticed that setting members using linq didn't seem to work. So I constructed this very specific code to show an example.

Why is the SomeClass instance's member not set in the first ForEach?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        public float val = 0f;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(x => new SomeClass());

        arr.ToList().ForEach(x => x.val = 2f);

        // Outputs 0
        Console.WriteLine(arr.Select(x => x.val).First());

        var list = arr.ToList();

        list.ForEach(x => x.val = 2f);

        // Outputs 2
        Console.WriteLine(list.Select(x => x.val).First());
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/j0oLUh

Comment: Why not just `Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(x => new SomeClass { val = 2f });`?

Comment: This test is by itself silly. It just illustrates the issue I ran into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never store the query in a collection, this works because of the `ToList()`:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(x => new SomeClass()).ToList();
list.ForEach(x => x.val = 2f);
```

Note that your `arr.ToList()` creates a collection, but it's never stored anywhere. So the `SomeClass` instances are also just temporary. Whenever you will access `arr` later you will create new instances. You should read about LINQ's deferred execution.

Comment: Maybe also add that `ForEach` is a `List<T>` method and not a `LinQ` one?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: true, it's a method from `List<>`. But i think it's not so important in this case. It would be the same if you'd use a `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Linq Select Query Add .ToList()